# is PeekMessageW function actually dispatching the message?

Tags: c++, winapi

In the documentation for Microsoft, it states [PeekMessageW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew)  ***dispatch*** the message if any.

But why in this case is there the  need of a [DispatchMessageW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessagew) function ?  The few example I could gather use both together, calling DispatchMessage after PeekMessage/GetMessage.

I also can observe experimentally that peekMessage does not dispatch the message but seems to only give a look at the message queue.

Comment: PeekMessage dispatches sent messages. You use DispatchMessage in your message loop to dispatch queued messages.

Comment: Read the _Remarks_ section on the first page that you link to.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of [PeekMessageW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew) is documented:

> During this call, the system delivers pending, nonqueued messages, that is, messages sent to windows owned by the calling thread using the [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage), [SendMessageCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagecallbackw), [SendMessageTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeoutw), or [SendNotifyMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendnotifymessagew) function. Then the first queued message that matches the specified filter is retrieved.

[Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/messages-and-message-queues) explains the terminology as well as the underlying principles.